Torch cant be imported
Can someone help me? I'm trying to run a training script for a module, and the first error I got in the command prompt was this:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘torch’
But I already have it installed. Here are the commands O ran and the outputs I got:
C:\Users\moham\Desktop\mohamad\uni\thesis>pip install torch
Requirement already satisfied: torch in c:\users\moham\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in c:\users\moham\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from torch) (3.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.8.0 in c:\users\moham\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from torch) (4.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in c:\users\moham\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from torch) (1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in c:\users\moham\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from torch) (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\users\moham\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from torch) (3.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: fsspec in c:\users\moham\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from torch) (2024.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\users\moham\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from jinja2->torch) (2.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in c:\users\moham\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from sympy->torch) (1.3.0)

C:\Users\moham\Desktop\mohamad\uni\thesis>where python
C:\Users\moham.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims\python
C:\Users\moham.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims\python.bat
C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

C:\Users\moham\Desktop\mohamad\uni\thesis>python -c “import site; print(site.getsitepackages())”
[‘C:\Users\moham\.pyenv\\pyenv-win\versions\3.13.0a6’, ‘C:\Users\moham\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.13.0a6\Lib\site-packages’]

C:\Users\moham\Desktop\mohamad\uni\thesis>pip install torch
C:\Users\moham\Desktop\mohamad\uni\thesis>where python
C:\Users\moham\Desktop\mohamad\uni\thesis>python -c “import site; print(site.getsitepackages())”


Do you see that torch is installed in c:\users\moham\appdata\local\packages, but your python is using C:\Users\moham.pyenv\pyenv-win ?

Seems like your pip command is using python3.10, and you've also configured pyenv to use Python 3.13... You can use python -m pip install torch to ensure packages are installed into the correct environment (however, you may not want an alpha release of Python).
Otherwise, you'll want to adjust how pyenv is set on the PATH

sorry for the very late reply but apparently i just needed to download it in a separate environment not on my main machine + the new version still had some bugs had to use older version
